# Kohana 3.3: How do I create routes for an admin sub-directory?

Tags: php, web-applications, routes, kohana-3, subdirectory

I have set up two routes, one is the default and the other is one to enable the admin section which has controllers in a sub-directory of the controller directory. These are how they look like:

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'Home',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));

// Admin routes
Route::set('admin', 'admin(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
        ->defaults(array(
                'directory'  => 'Admin',
                'controller' => 'Main',
                'action'     => 'index',
        ));
```

When I navigate to /admin/ or /admin/main I get a 404 error and I can't get it to work. I've also named the classes in the admin sub-directory as Controller_Admin_Main so that should work, right?

Please provide examples to how this should be done correctly. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem got fixed by switching the position of the admin route to above the default route in the code. I guess kohana matched the first expression and tried to show a view according to the default route.